# Search for questions/answers you voted on

Tags: feature-request, voting, search

Currently the only [user operators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) search has is `user:*id*`, `infavorites:*id*`, and `intags:mine`. I suggest a new operator `invoted:` with the options `invoted:all`, `invoted:up` and `invoted:down`. These would return any questions or answers where you cast any kind a vote, a upvote, or a downvote respectively.

The value this tag would add to this site would be easier searching of duplicate questions. I have seen questions that I know I have seen a duplicate for but searching does not return the result I was looking for, I remember casting a upvote on the question and/or the answer to the question but I did not favorite the question nor did I comment on it.

If I was able to limit the search to questions and answers I had cast a vote on I could use that plus a few key words for finding the duplicate and the result would be a reasonable number that I could hand look through to find the old question I am searching for.

Comment: For that one, I would also want the reverse. And as you only have access to your own votes anyway, better make it `voted:yes/no/all`.

Comment: @Deduplicator `-invoted:mine` would do the reverse, although I could see the benefit of being able to search `invoted:up/down/all`

Comment: I was thinking all the years that not being able to easily find questions you voted on was on purpose. It is such a basic feature... Like PHP not having `finally`, Java not having properties, and JS having variable hoisting (some have changed their minds, though).

Comment: Considering that 44 people have voted for this, is there anything we can do to bring this to Stack Overflow staff attention?

Comment: Although it is not possible to search for Votes answers now, you can search for bookmarks, `inbookmarks:mine hello`, provided that the questions need to be bookmarked.