# Search through Votes Tab

Tags: feature-request

I would like to know when did I cast a vote in a specific answer. I know I can go to the Votes Tab in my profile, but there are hundreds of votes, so it would help if there was a search box.

I want to know this date because I can match it against my activities log to find out what exactly was I working on when I cast that vote, and see if I'm runing on the same problem now and what I did then to solve it.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291357/search-for-questions-answers-you-voted-on

Comment: @rene Thanks. It's been one year...so I guess it is not gonna happen. =/

Comment: I recall having seen a similar request where someone offered to create a userscript but I can't find that one. Must have been deleted then.

Comment: @rene I find the link isn't related to the question, so OP wants to find the voting date for some question, not all questions(their are on Vote Tab) voted on.