# Searching enhancement proposal

Tags: feature-request, search

As the number of posts on this site grows, the role of the searching system is becoming more and more important. However, I feel our searching system is not powerful enough. Could we please have some "advanced" searching to narrow down the search results further? For example:

- Answers containing the keyword "Pythonic" and I've cast an upvote on.
- Questions which was tweeted/was selected as a Hot Network Question, and is tagged with `java`
- Answers I have viewed and contains the keyword "undefined behavior"(verbatim), sorted by the last-viewed date
- ……

I think we should be aware that, some day, the functionality of searching for existing posts would be more vital even than asking/answering new questions.

Comment: bullet 1 is a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291357/search-for-questions-answers-you-voted-on

Comment: _Questions which was tweeted/was selected as a Hot Network Question_ you can use the `views` option and set a high view rate, it won't guarantee that the question was/is a hot network question, but it will show a popular ones. And of course you can include the `[java]` tag too

Comment: You could use SEDE for at least some of this.

Comment: But I don't believe there's an alternative to the last bullet `……`

Comment: And for bullet #3, since Stack Overflow has been very resistant to track questions that you have viewed (mostly because your browser already does that for you), it doesn't seem feasible to implement

Comment: From MSE, on bullet #3, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54110/search-viewed-questions